# DragSortListView setOnItemClickListener and setOnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, onclicklistener

I have added the DragSortListView Library from Bauer and it works. The only problem that I have encountered is the ItemClickListeners. As they aren't doing anything. I have researched around and there are still no working answers.

Some answer I came across to solving my situation are

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    dslv:drag_start_mode="onMove"
```

but it didn't work

XML part

```
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
    xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.mobeta.android.dslv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="435dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    dslv:drag_start_mode="onMove"
    dslv:drag_enabled="true"
    dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
    dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
    dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
    dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
    dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
    dslv:track_drag_sort="false"
    dslv:use_default_controller="true"
    dslv:sort_enabled="false"
    dslv:remove_enabled="true"
    dslv:remove_mode="flingRemove"/>
```

my Fragment class

```
    db = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());
    data = db.getAllMeal();
    lv = (DragSortListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    final ArrayAdapter<RecipeDAO> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RecipeDAO>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setDropListener(new DragSortListView.DropListener() {
        @Override
        public void drop(int from, int to) {
            if (from != to) {
                RecipeDAO item = adapter.getItem(from);
                adapter.remove(item);
                adapter.insert(item, to);
                db.updateMealList(data);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, long id) {
            //db.deleteRecipe(data.get(position).getRecipeID());
            Crouton.makeText(getActivity()," deleted", Style.CONFIRM).setConfiguration(new Configuration.Builder().setDuration(700).build()).show();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity()," deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: And I assume your listeners work when you are just using a plain old ListView?

Comment: yes listener work fine when i use the standard listview.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to declare a drag handle.
If you are only using this for remove, perhaps GestureListener would be a better solution.

Comment: forgot to mention planned to click the item and open a dialoginterface box